# How to split the left and right camera images (HTC Evo 3D) in the camera preview data

Tags: android, 3d, camera

Now I have the HTC Evo 3D with two rear cameras, and plan to do some stereovision experiments. I accessed the stereo camera using the following code:

```
private final static int CAMERA_STEREOSCOPIC 
= Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH ? 2 : 100;
camera = Camera.open(CAMERA_STEREOSCOPIC);
```

To access the camera preview data:

```
bufferSize = mPreviewWidth * mPreviewHeight * bitsPerPixel / 8;
mPreviewBuffer = null;

// New preview buffer.
mPreviewBuffer = new byte[bufferSize + 4096];

// with buffer requires addbuffer.
camera.addCallbackBuffer(mPreviewBuffer);
camera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(mCameraCallback);

private final Camera.PreviewCallback mCameraCallback = new Camera.PreviewCallback() {
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera c) {
        // to do the camera image split processing using "data"
}
};
```

**But what's the size and data structure of the preview data here, and how could I split the left and right camera images in the camera preview code?**

BTW, should I pay attention on the buffer size of preview data for two cameras?

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Get a solution by myself: add the opencv4android library and there are related code in its samples to rapidly convert the camera frame (yuv420s) to rgba and then display the left and right images on an ImageView. Just for the reference.

Comment: Hey, I'm using OpenCV4Android java interface to do the same. but I'm unable to use both back cameras. I'm using CameraBridgeViewBase to access the camera. I tried different indices. 0 gives top-back camera. 1 gives front camera. -1 gives the same top-back camera. how to access down-back camera?